# How to know the number of circuits through my middle Tor relay?

Tags: relays, circuit, middle

I am running my Tor relay as middle relay. Is it possible to know how many circuits are there through my middle relay?

Answer (score 1):

With [Arm](https://www.torproject.org/projects/arm.html.en) you should see the inbound connections. That number represents the number of incoming connections and therefore it represents also the number of circuits.